# What does it mean when the US cops wear the badges or T-shirts saying "I am the kneeling officer"?

Tags: united-states, police

What does it mean when the US police officers or other people wear the badges or T-shirts saying "I am the kneeling officer"? What about the collective kneeling actions?
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I don't know where you've read about such badges, but the caption for the Photo you've posted (found via reverse image search) [is](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/police-officers-kneel-during-a-rally-in-coral-gables-news-photo/1216403564):

> Police officers kneel during a rally in Coral Gables, Florida on May 30, 2020 in response to the recent death of George Floyd, an unarmed black man who died while being arrested and pinned to the ground by a Minneapolis police officer. - Clashes broke out and major cities imposed curfews as America began another night of unrest Saturday with angry demonstrators ignoring warnings from President Donald Trump that his government would stop violent protests over police brutality "cold." (Photo by Eva Marie UZCATEGUI / AFP)

In some [other news](https://abc7news.com/george-floyd-protests-kneel-santa-cruz-police/6225187/) around the same time (from other locations) police officers as shown kneeling together with the protesters.

And that was apparently [also the case](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/protesters-police-kneel-solidarity-george-floyd/) for the context of the image you've posted:

> In Coral Gables, a city near Miami, a peaceful protest attended by hundreds on Saturday included a moment of prayer with police officers, CBS Miami reported. Powerful images from the demonstration show officers kneeling, heads bowed, in solidarity with protesters. Some protesters chanted "Black lives matter!" and "No justice, no peace, no racist police."

Answer (score 4):

This is a reference to [American football players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._national_anthem_protests_(2016%E2%80%93present)) who started kneeling during the playing of the national anthem as a protest against police brutality. They chose kneeling because it was a way of making a protest without being overtly disrespectful. It is however, highly contentious in the US whether that is actually the case.

In particular, President Trump called on the athletes involved to be fired. So by kneeling, the police officers concerned are taking a side in a highly charged political issue.